# Call function once at end of each loop

Tags: javascript, each

How can I call a function once at the end of an each loop.

This alerts 'finished' on each loop, I want it once when the loop has finished.

```
    $(function(){

      var imgArr=[];

      var lis = $('#gallery li')

      lis.each(function(){
        imgArr.push(this.outerHTML);
        $(this).remove();
        alertFun();
      })

      function alertFun(){
        alert('finished');
      }

    })
```

Comment: Why not just move the call to *after* the loop?

Comment: This is a really funny question...

Comment: The code is just a sample, I wanted the alert function to call when the each has finished. If I move it after the loop might it go before the loop has finished?

Answer (score 2):

```
function alertFun(){
  alert('finished');
}

lis.each(function(){
  imgArr.push(this.outerHTML);
  $(this).remove();
})

alertFun();
```

Or am I missing something?

Edit: Based on your comment I think I know where you're coming from now.

You supply each with a callback function. However, don't confuse this with an asychronous call. Although you supply each with a callback in the same way you would an asychronous call such as `ajax` or `animate`, the call is sychronous and executed in order.

Also remember that `function alertFun(){ ... }` is a declaration, not a call.

Comment: Yea.. idk. I think we both might be missing something `+1`

Comment: I think the alertFun will fire before the each loop has finished?

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but:

```
$(function(){

  var imgArr=[];

  var lis = $('#gallery li');

  lis.each(function(){
    imgArr.push(this.outerHTML);
    $(this).remove();
  });

  alert('finished');//ta da

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Previous code

lis.each(function(){
  imgArr.push(this.outerHTML);
  $(this).remove();

})

alertFun();

function alertFun()...
```